# Monitoring Apache Spark Logs and the Dynamic App/Driver logs

Tags: logging, apache-spark, log4j

We are running a spark-streaming application on a standalone setup (version 1.6).

The logging in spark seems to be a bit scattered and I am attempting to configure a nagios log file monitor that checks for certain "errors" in log files and sends out alerts.

My current understanding in regards to logs for spark are the following:

1. Spark-Worker has it's own logs and in my case it's written to a
   static location /var/log/spark/spark-worker.out
2. Spark-Master has it's own logs and in my case it's written to a
   static location /var/log/spark/spark-master.out
3. I can configure the log4j.properties file under /etc/spark/conf/ to
   alter format, appenders etc.. for spark-worker and spark-master logs

***Now for Driver and Spark/Executor App logs*** 
It seems the location for these logs are dynamic and spark will generated new directories under /var/run/spark/work in my case.

***My issue:***

Monitoring the static location log files is straight forward for spark-worker and spark-master. I am a bit confused as to how the dynamic logs for app and drivers can be monitored.

From what I read in the documentation, it seems upon spark-submit I can pass a -D option with a location to a log4j.properties file.

Can this be configured to stream the logs to a local syslog in a static location and then have nagios monitor that static log?

What have others done in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Is it yarn or spark standalone. If you are using yarn, you can get all the consolidated logs using the command

```
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID> <options>
```

Comment: Its for standalone setup